# Is WSA compiler in Boo safe to use?

Tags: .net, macros, dsl, boo

In our program we use boo as macro system about 2 years. All works like a charm, but python syntax is weird for newcomers. As I know boo has white space agnostic (WSA) compiler with ruby like syntax:
instead of

```
def Hello():
  print 'Hello'
```

you can write:

```
def Hello(): #notice colon!!!
print 'Hello'
end
```

here is ideal :)

```
def Hello()
  print 'Hello ruby'
end
```

1. Is it safe to use?
2. Can it be used with default syntax side by side?
3. Can I covert a **huge** number of existing macros to WSA style?
4. Can I add 'extra' colons via compiler step

Comment: Erm.... in the second example, I actually *didn't* notice a comma...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't claim to know the answers to these questions, but it might help you to know that the [Brail ViewEngine uses WSA Boo](http://fisheye2.atlassian.com/browse/castleproject/MonoRail/trunk/src/Castle.MonoRail.Views.Brail/BooViewEngine.cs?r=6245#l716) and [it has a few macros](http://fisheye2.atlassian.com/browse/castleproject/MonoRail/trunk/src/Castle.MonoRail.Views.Brail/Macros) (written in C# though). You might want to look into that code.

Comment: thanks, only difference with my code is WSABooParsingStep. I'll check that.